# Derivatives of Functions on set of Linear Maps

Tags: matrices, derivatives, differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the algebra of linear maps to itself.

Let $F_k:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ such that $F_k(A)=A^k $ for $k=1,2,\dots$

and

$G:GL(n,R) \rightarrow GL(n,R)$ such that $G(A)=A^{-1} $.

I want to show that these functions are differentiable and compute their derivatives. Is there a standard metric that I should be using, or should one proceed with the definition of the derivative, with an arbitrary metric?

In general, how important is it to actually specify the metric in situations such as this once one shows that a metric does exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spaces are finite dimensional manifolds, so metrics are not needed. Each $F_k$ is differentiable because the entries of $A^k$ are polynomial in the entries of $A$, and $G$ is differentiable because the entries of $A^{-1}$ are rational functions of the entries of $A$. The formulas $$DF_k(A)(H) =\sum_{i=1}^k A^{i-1}HA^{k-i}\quad\mbox{and}\quad DG(A)(H) = -A^{-1}HA^{-1}$$hold. The first is the product rule. For the second, write $AG(A)=I$ and differentiate to get $HA^{-1}+A\,DG(A)(H)=0$ --- then solve for $DG(A)(H)$.